# Kubernetes Deployment Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my web service to Google Container Engine:

Here's my **deployment.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: handfree
  labels:
    app: handfree
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: handfree
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: handfree
        image: arycloud/mysecretrepo:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        #Ports to expose
        ports:
        - name: api_port
          containerPort: 8000
```

Here's my **service.yaml:**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  #Service name
  name: judge
spec:
  selector:
    app: handfree
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I have created a cluster on Google Container Engine with cluster size 4 and 8 vCPUs, I have successfully get credentials by using the command from connecting link of this cluster.

When I try to run the deployment.yml it returns an error as:

> Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of: default handfree    deployment.yaml
>
> from server for: "deployment.yaml" deployments.extensions "handfree" is forbidden: User "client" cannot get deployments.extensions in the namespace "default": Unknown user "client".

I'm new to kubernetes world, help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Unknown user "client".

Means there is no [`RoleBinding`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#rolebinding-v1-rbac-authorization-k8s-io) or [`ClusterRoleBinding`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#clusterrolebinding-v1-rbac-authorization-k8s-io) with a [`subjects:`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#subject-v1beta1-rbac-authorization-k8s-io) of `type: User` with a `name:` of `client`.

The fix is to create a `ClusterRoleBinding` or `RoleBinding` -- depending on whether you want `client` to have access to **every** `Namespace` or just `default` -- and point it at an existing (or created) `Role` or `ClusterRole`. The bad news is that since your current credential is invalid, you will need to track down the `cluster-admin` credential to be able to make that kind of change. Since I haven't used GKE, I can't specify the exact steps.

I know those paragraphs are filled with jargon, and for that I'm sorry - it's a complex topic. There are several RBAC summaries, including a [recent one from GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/08/07/understanding-kubernestes-rbac/), a [CNCF webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnHTCTP8d48), and [one from Sysdig](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-security-rbac-tls/), and (of course) [the kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)